# Token-based authentication and session/local storage on browsers

Tags: node.js, session, authentication, cookies, local-storage

Alright, I want to implement a web app that uses authentication mechanisms for personalizing the user experience on a website but meanwhile I have some questions I want to clear up. So, in the beginning, users will login with their username and password (let's forget 3rd party authentication for now and assume there is an appropriate signup page) and upon successful login, the server will generate a token to be used for subsequent calls from the browser for that particular user. In what follows I am trying to verify my understanding and ask the relevant questions.

As far as I understand using a token is much faster (less cpu-intensive if you prefer) on the server side, because now one will not have to decrypt the password that is stored on the server and compare it to the one sent with the request (for example using [bcrypt](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/)), but instead the check is much simpler and boils down to whether the token has expired or not. As an additional benefit, the sensitive information of the username and password is not transmitted repeatedly.

**Checkpoint 1.** We want the app to be robust when the user voluntarily or accidentally presses "Refresh/Reload", so that the token can still be used after the refresh (and not have to login again with the credentials). It is now clear that either we have to use a cookie (i.e. sessions), or utilize session storage or local storage on the client side. Is there another way? As far as I understand, the answer is no (yes, there are different options for local storage like Web Storage, Web SQL Database, Indexed Database, and File Access, but that is beyond the question). Is this right or wrong? Further, what is the most commonly used practice for dealing with tokens (storage/recall) on the client side?

**Checkpoint 2.** Expiration of the tokens. As far as I understand, the idea is that every time one uses a valid token, the expiration time for that particular token is renewed (say 7 or 10 days later). This has the nice benefit that users that visit regularly the site need to sign in only once. The downside though appears to be that it is implied that the token remains the same - potentially for ever - for the same user (unless of course the token expires). The question then is, is this safe? Another idea here is to update the token on the backend, send the updated token on the client side and update the token on the local storage of the browser, while everything is transparent to the end user. Is this a common practice? I can see that now on the server side one needs to be cautious on the tokens that are generated (see the scenario below). Are there common practices for dealing with this (if one needs to deal with it at all)?

(Assume user A has two devices A1 and A2 using token TA1 that expires in 7 days from now, and user B has device B1 using token TB1 that expires in 7 days from now. All the tokens are stored in some sort of local storage. Six days later (i.e. a day before the actual expiration), TA1 is updated to TA2 while user A is using device A1. Similarly on that day TB1 is updated to TA1. Now if user A uses the device A2, the guy has a valid token (TA1), but will authenticate as user B while using the API!)

**Checkpoint 3.** I have assumed all along that token-based authentication is just that. A single token sent through the headers of the http requests and that is all. Clearly, if one also sends the username, then we avoid sending the password and we also avoid the problematic scenario I described above. However, there is something I do not like much with this approach. After all, now the token acts as a password. The only saving is that of decryption (i.e. cpu-cycles) while matching the credentials on the server side. Is this approach nonsense or what?

**Checkpoint 4.** If in the future one wants to create a dedicated app for say a smartphone or a tablet, it is (supposedly) much easier to use tokens on the headers of the requests rather than relying on cookies and sessions (see cookie containers). This is minor to me at the moment, but is it true?

I think the above questions are implementation agnostic, but if you want to give pointers for the development, I will be using node.js.

Comment: All of you guys who are voting this thread to close, could you care writing a sentence or two justifying your vote? Are my questions really open-ended or irrelevant to Stack Overflow?

Comment: It is rather broad or opinion based. You could check the help center of programmers to see if it fits there. I would try to keep it to one question at the time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: Cookies are the preferred method of storing tokens client-side.

2: You can either re-auth the user and send an updated token back, or simply delay the expiration of the token. This largely depends on how you're storing the tokens, and are handling the expiration mechanism (e.g. Mongo's Time to Live mechanism, or an 'expiresAt' field in a SQL database, etc). The scenario you outline with a user hijacking another user's session should not be possible with proper token generation.

3: Token should be the only that is needed to auth the user. On the server side, once you have the token you'd simply perform an operation to retrieve the user object. This largely depends on how you've set your system up. For instance you can set it up so that the signed token is decoded directly into a user object, or if you're using a persistant storage to store the tokens, use the token as the key in your query.

4: When sending the token, you're better of using the headers of the request regardless of the platform. Cookies, local storage etc are merely tools to persist the token on the user's device.

If you're using Node.js for your app, I recommend checking out the way auth is handled in something [angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/) which uses Passport with an External Bearer strategy that is similar to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am of course up-voting for the effort and the time that you took to write a few things down. The only funny thing in this process to me is that (1) suggests using a cookie so that we can store the token on the client side (and thus a cookie will be going back and forth forever), while (4) suggests sending the token on the headers (which is what I also prefer). I understand that cookies might be preferable for compatibility reasons with old IE variants (instead of local storage), but this seems just wrong to me. In any case, thank you for your time.

Comment: I will not accept yet, as I would like to see an extra comment or two. If no-one else writes down something, I will accept your answer.

Comment: You're right as far as the cookie is concerned, a lot of it has to do with compatibility issues, and not entirely necessary in the majority of cases. However, this is something you can control client-side as you can check whether something like session/local storage is available, if so use it, else default to cookies.